# I am trying to receive user input as a String message and convert (parse) it to integers to store in an array in Android

Tags: android

I am having trying to receive user input as a String representing numbers in my lottery android app. I am then parsing this user input to integers and storing in an array, to be compared with another array of integers. However I am having the following problem in that I am getting a type mismatch: cannot convert from an int to a String. I have created an activity that displays the user message, but I want this to be stored in the array, which would be their lottery ticket numbers. I have a button that links to this new "display numbers activity". I have created a global variable "static String [] userNumbers = new String[SIZE] and have set the constant size to = 6.

I am getting the mismatch error in the section of code that parses the String to an int and an error in the for loop to set up the array. Hope someone can help me solve this problem. Thanks in advance!

My code is below:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    public final static String EXTRA_MESSAGE = ".com.example.lotterychecker.MESSAGE";
    static boolean bonus = false;
    static boolean jackpot = false;
    static int lottCount = 0;
    final static int SIZE =6; 
    static String [] userNumbers = new String[SIZE]; 
    Button check;

//...some code for parsing html......

public void checkNumbers(View view) {
        //create an intent to display the numbers
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, DisplayNumbersActivity.class);
        EditText editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.enter_numbers);
        String message = editText.getText().toString();
        intent.putExtra(EXTRA_MESSAGE, message );
        startActivity(intent);

        String userNumbers = editText.getText().toString();
        userNumbers = Integer.parseInt(message); //mismatch error here
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Here are your numbers", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        for (int count =0; count < SIZE; count ++)
        {
            if (check.isPressed())
            {
                userNumbers[count] = editText.getText().toString(); //error "The type of the expression must be an array type  
                                                                    //but it resolved to String" in the userNumbers[count] syntax
            }
        }//for
    }



public class DisplayNumbersActivity extends Activity {

    @SuppressLint("NewApi")
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_display_numbers);
        // Show the Up button in the action bar.
        setupActionBar();

        //get the message from the intent
        Intent intent = getIntent();
        String message = intent.getStringExtra(MainActivity.EXTRA_MESSAGE);

        //create the text view
        TextView textView = new TextView(this);
        textView.setTextSize(40);
        textView.setText(message);

        //set the text view as the activity layout
        setContentView(textView);
    }
```

Comment: Have you looked at what the `message` actually is just before you get the mismatch error?

Comment: Please post the stacktrace

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this line

```
String userNumbers = editText.getText().toString();
```

you define a local variable `userNumbers` of type String. This definition makes the class field `userNumbers` which is an array unaccessible.

You also try to store an int in the String variable. This is a type mismatch.

Comment: He's right. everything under Srting userNumbers = .... cant "see" the array anymore. So what you are acually do is trying to write a string into a char variable - which cant be.
All you have to do is change the name of one of the two variables. And besides that,  @SuppressLint("NewApi") is also most often a bad idea..

Comment: also it shoudld be `int numbervalue = Integer.parseInt(message)` and should be enclosed withing a try catch block